# PHP calculate suggested price value

Tags: php

I have below variable

> 1. quantity ($qty)
> 2. purchase price ($pp)
> 3. sale price ($sp)
> 4. commission 12% ($comm)
> 5. suggested sale price

the commission is calculated on the sale price for example if the sale price increase commission will increase too.

I want to calculate the Suggested sale price on a 10% profit ratio ($pr)

here is my code

```
$comm=12; //(commission 12%)
$pr=10; //(10% profit)

$percent = ((float)$sp/100)*(float)$comm;
$fees=round($percent,2);

$total=((float)$pp*(float)$qty)+(float)$fees;

$profit = ((float)$total/100)*(float)$pr;
$suggested = round(((float)$profit)+((float)$total),2);
```

I am calling this ajax function on button click, this will give few times different values on button click.
I think this is because when the sale price increase commission also increased based on that sale price.

there is no error in code only issue is it did't calculate correct value of  sale price on first call, it need 2 or 3 calls to get correct value. how can I get correct value in first call.

Comment: Find out why you’re sending different values, and make sure you send the right values the first time. It’s not just pulling values out of thin air.

Comment: dear its not about sending value, its about how its calculating like every time you change price, commission will change also

Comment: It would be helpful to see an example or two of desired output given certain input, vs what is actually happening. You stated that every time you press the button you get a different value back, as if the script were giving inconsistent results. Sample data will make your intent more clear and reproducible.

Comment: Hello, thanks dear but how much clear I should wrote, I just need to calculate suggested sale price in php but correct one please

Comment: I spent some time thinking about it last night, thinking it would be fairly simple algebra. The problem is in forcing net profit to be a certain percentage of sale price, while commissions also affect sale price... I end up trying to solve for two variables. It would be very helpful to have an example of the values of what you consider to be a correct answer. Note also that you have neglected cogs (cost of goods sold) which is imperative to finding profit. Need to incorporate that somehow. If you will include some examples of correct values, I’ll see if I can suggest an algorithm.

Comment: Thanks so much. yes here is values item cost is: 1.90$ and I want to calculate its sale price on basis of 15% profit & cogs (cost of goods sold) or I say commission is: 19%, I just need to know correct sale price?

Comment: What I was looking for was something like what I put under the "Test" section of my answer.  Fortunately, the algebra finally clicked for me.

Answer (score 0):

First, a disclaimer: I’m a programmer, not an accountant.

So, thinking out loud for a few moments:

#### Define Terms

```
cogs:   cost of goods sold (item cost)
sp:     sales price
comm:   commission 
profit: profit
```

#### Formulas

```
profit = sales price - cogs - comm
profit = sales price * profitPercentage
comm = sales price * commPercentage
```

#### Substitute

```
sales price * profitPercentage = sales price - cogs - comm
```

For sake of example, let’s assume profit is 10% and commission is 15%

```
sales price * .10 = sales price - cogs - comm
```

we can then substitute commission

```
sales price * .10 = sales price - cogs - (sales price * .15)
```

#### Simplify

```
.1(sales price) = sales price - cogs - .15(sales price)
cogs = sales price - .1(sales price) - .15(sales price)
cogs = (1 - .1 - .15)(sales price)
cogs = (.75)(sales price)
sales price = cogs/.75
```

#### Test

cogs: $10
price: $13.33
comm: $2.00
profit: $1.33

#### Code

```
function calculateSalesPrice(float $cogs, float $commPercent, float $profitPercent) : float
{
    $divisor = (1 - $commPercent - $profitPercent);
    if($divisor <= 0) { 
        throw new Exception('Commission and Profit exceed 100%');    
    }
    return round(($cogs/$divisor),2);
}
```

With this formula, both profit and commission use the sales price as their basis.